# Expanding a daily roster in pandas to join with other files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create an efficient roster to keep track of people and what team they are on, who they report to, etc, on any given date. I imagine inputting one new row for any change that the people has.

My challenge is how do I show that the person had the same information for all of the other dates in between changes? For example, if I was to `pd.merge` this file with another file with daily data, I would want to show that person `a1` reported to `Tim` everyday from `5/1` - `5/9`, and then on `5/10` onwards they reported to `John`.

```
Effective_Date  EmpID   Manager Team    Current
      5/1/2015  a1       Tim    11       No
      5/10/2015 a1       John   5        Yes
      5/1/2015  a2       Steve  11       No
      5/3/2015  a3       Steve  1        No
      5/25/2015 a2       Steve  3        Yes
      5/4/2015  a3       Tim    9        Yes
```

So if I had a list of dates from `5/1` - `10/1`, I would expect to see each `EmpID` have a row for each date.

```
Date    EmpID   Manager Team    Current
5/1/2015    a1  Tim 11  No
5/2/2015    a1  Tim 11  No
5/3/2015    a1  Tim 11  No
5/4/2015    a1  Tim 11  No
5/5/2015    a1  Tim 11  No
5/6/2015    a1  Tim 11  No
5/7/2015    a1  Tim 11  No
5/8/2015    a1  Tim 11  No
5/9/2015    a1  Tim 11  No
5/10/2015   a1  John    5   Yes
5/11/2015   a1  John    5   Yes
5/12/2015   a1  John    5   Yes
5/13/2015   a1  John    5   Yes
5/14/2015   a1  John    5   Yes
5/15/2015   a1  John    5   Yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I added one row to each group - because Manager is active today.

You can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `EmpID` and [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.resample.html) by `days` and fill rows by method `how=first`.

Then I reset multiindex - first drop first duplicity level and then reset again.

```
print df
  Effective_Date EmpID Manager  Team Current
0     2015-05-01    a1     Tim    11      No
1     2015-05-10    a1    John     5     Yes
2     2015-05-01    a2   Steve    11      No
3     2015-05-03    a3   Steve     1      No
4     2015-05-25    a2   Steve     3     Yes
5     2015-05-04    a3     Tim     9     Yes
```

```
import datetime as dt

lastRowIndex = df.groupby('EmpID').Effective_Date.idxmax()
rows = df.ix[lastRowIndex]
rows['Effective_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dt.date.today())
df = pd.concat([df,rows], ignore_index=True)
df = df.sort_values(['EmpID', 'Effective_Date'], ascending=True)
print df

  Effective_Date EmpID Manager  Team Current
0     2015-05-01    a1     Tim    11      No
1     2015-05-10    a1    John     5     Yes
6     2015-11-28    a1    John     5     Yes
2     2015-05-01    a2   Steve    11      No
4     2015-05-25    a2   Steve     3     Yes
7     2015-11-28    a2   Steve     3     Yes
3     2015-05-03    a3   Steve     1      No
5     2015-05-04    a3     Tim     9     Yes
8     2015-11-28    a3     Tim     9     Yes
```

```
df = df.groupby(['EmpID']).apply(lambda x: x.set_index('Effective_Date').resample('D', how='first',fill_method='ffill'))
df = df.reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index()
print df.head(20)
  Effective_Date EmpID Manager  Team Current
0      2015-05-01    a1     Tim    11      No
1      2015-05-02    a1     Tim    11      No
2      2015-05-03    a1     Tim    11      No
3      2015-05-04    a1     Tim    11      No
4      2015-05-05    a1     Tim    11      No
5      2015-05-06    a1     Tim    11      No
6      2015-05-07    a1     Tim    11      No
7      2015-05-08    a1     Tim    11      No
8      2015-05-09    a1     Tim    11      No
9      2015-05-10    a1    John     5     Yes
10     2015-05-11    a1    John     5     Yes
11     2015-05-12    a1    John     5     Yes
12     2015-05-13    a1    John     5     Yes
13     2015-05-14    a1    John     5     Yes
14     2015-05-15    a1    John     5     Yes
15     2015-05-16    a1    John     5     Yes
16     2015-05-17    a1    John     5     Yes
17     2015-05-18    a1    John     5     Yes
18     2015-05-19    a1    John     5     Yes
19     2015-05-20    a1    John     5     Yes
```

Comment: I think that is a good solution. Thanks. Only problem is that it should go forward until at least the current date. The issue is that the roster stops on the last effective date (EmpID a1, for example, stops on 5/10 even though there is data up until at least 5/12). My current solution is that I have a separate roster for each day. I read that all into memory and do my joins so I know who the manager was during a certain time period.

Comment: Yest, it stop to current day. I don't understand your last 5 rows of recommended output. How can I know, what is last day? Why is it `5/15/2015`?

Comment: Employees might have any changes for a few months at a time. They will report to someone for a month or two, and then someone else after that. The last effective date (max date) should be their current status for all dates afterwards too. Like what if I was going to look at November data and try to see who the Manager of a1 was?  a1 switched to John on 5/10 and that was his last change, so that should be his current Manager even today.

Comment: Yes, I think this will work well. I wonder if there are other best practices. I assume that a lot of people have to deal with the issue of 'who was reporting to who on a certain date' when they are joining data together. Thanks a bunch.